Group ranked and overlapping rows by range in Postgresql *keeping only the top row*
I have a dataset which lists bids to use a continuous series e.g. roadside frontage, which can be identified with a start and end chainage (decimal value).
Developers have made bids to use a certain amount of road frontage. I want to screen these by a) ranking them based on the highest bid, then
b) roll them up so that any bids that overlap with a higher-ranked bid are discarded.
I have created a NUMRANGE from the start and end chainage:
with rg as 
(select numrange(start_ch_km, end_ch_km,'[]'), * from recieved_bids tr order by bid_price desc)
select * from rg rg1 join rg rg2 on rg1.numrange && rg2.numrange

This gives me the highest bids overlapping with lower bids.  However I cannot figure out a way to either GROUP or PARTITION in a way that ignores a bid if it overlaps with a higher ranked bid, leaving the space free for lower-ranked bids. In the image below, I would like to return only rank 1, 4 and 7.
Can this be done with GROUP BY or PARTITION? Or would I have to use  a RECURSIVE function.


How should bids with the same ranking and overlapping chainage be handled?

There are a finite number of bids and they have numeric numbers - rather than integers - so the likelihood of them having exactly the same value is low. If this case were to arise, my instinct would be to prioritise the one that had the shorter range as this is delivering the same bid and using fewer resources,  so is provides more value.

"Unlikely" is not the same as "impossible." Logic that usually, but not always, produces the correct answer is still incorrect. Precise and complete definitions are necessary if unexpected results are to be avoided; e.g, in the original post, it's stated that bids are for a certain amount of frontage, but the graph and use of the word overlap indicates that bids are for specific sections of the frontage. If the goal is to maximize the value of the accepted bids, then a more sophisticated appoach is necessary (see Knapsack problem).

This is probably most easily achieved using a recursive cte. In the code below I've used the first cte to rank the bids in order of descending price and then the recursive part of the query loops through each of these bids in turn, accepting them if there is no overlap with any of the previously accepted bids which are stored as a multirange that is updated with each accepted bid.
create table received_bids (
  id integer generated always as identity,
  start_ch_km numeric not null,
  end_ch_km numeric not null,
  bid_price numeric not null
  );

insert into received_bids (start_ch_km, end_ch_km, bid_price)
values (5, 25, 8),
       (0, 15, 7),
       (15, 45, 6),
       (55, 85, 5),
       (35, 85, 4),
       (45, 65, 3),
       (35, 45, 2),
       (5, 85, 1);

with recursive ranked_bids as (
    select row_number() over(order by bid_price desc) as rank_id,
           numrange(start_ch_km, end_ch_km) as chainage
    from received_bids
    ),
cte (cumulative, bid_accepted, rank_id) as (
    select '{}'::nummultirange, false, 0::bigint
    union all
    select case when ranked_bids.chainage && cte.cumulative 
                then cte.cumulative
                else cte.cumulative + ranked_bids.chainage::nummultirange
           end,
           not ranked_bids.chainage && cte.cumulative,
           ranked_bids.rank_id
    from cte
    join ranked_bids on ranked_bids.rank_id = cte.rank_id + 1
    )
select rank_id
from cte
where bid_accepted;


Thank you @EAW for the quick response. I will digest and try this.
